# jquery API CORS issue when specifying headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling an API from different domain, it doesn't have any authorization check for now but in future we are planning to do so. When I hit this API without any headers I get the response but when I set the headers the browser throws CORS error. the headers are appID, version and empID. "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is set on server side. I am using another API from another domain which works perfectly fine with and without headers. I think the issue is with content-type or data-type but I am clueless.I get the response in JSON format.

Comment: Is the API developed with any framework of php or core php ? And is that API is also developed by you ?

Comment: Is it any framework of php or core php ?

Comment: If you add custom headers then the browser will send a pre-flight query using the `OPTIONS` HTTP method.  Are you sure that your API server is correctly responding to that?

Comment: If API is built with with a framework, then I can tell you specifically what to do.

Comment: Android engineer developed the API using Java with swagger.io

Comment: Use Chrome and its developer tools, look at the Network connections tab, and you'll probably see that `OPTIONS` request go past, and get rejected by the server API.

Comment: On network tab there is only one entry for API call and this is the result:

      {
      "code": 7,
      "message": "The service does not allow CORS traffic.",
      "details": [
      {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
          "stackEntries": [],
          "detail": "service_control"
       }
    ]
  }

Comment: In console there is 

OPTIONS - 403 ()
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://link.... Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: That's *exactly* what I suggested was happening in my first comment.   Your server API needs to be updated to support answering the `OPTIONS` request and sending back the CORS headers in that, too.

Comment: How do I do that?? backend is JAVA and API is built using swagger.io

Comment: I don't know, I've never used swagger.io - you'll have to pass the problem back to the server developer

Comment: Okay, I'll let you know if it works or not

Comment: @Alnitak still not working. Added headers in doOptions() servlet

Comment: Why negative votes??

Comment: probably because you've a) not included any error messages, and b) not included any (server side) code.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass non-standard headers to an AJAX request, the client will send a [pre-flight `OPTIONS` HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) before attempting the real request.

Your server needs to be able to handle that request, and also return the required ACAO headers in response to it.